# GTM tag fires multiple times after first click

Tags: google-tag-manager

On my category list page, I have created a tag that is triggered when a user clicks the "Add" button. The tag fires as expected, however, when I add a second product it fires the "add_to_cart" event two times, a third product three times, a fourth product four, etc.

[image]

I have Custom HTML tag set up that gets the product information when the "Add" button is clicked, and then pushes to the data layer:

[image]

Here is the full HTML:

```
<script type=“text/javascript”>
(function() {

document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

var element = event.target;
var divId = element.closest('.card').id;

var productSku = document.querySelector("#" + divId + " > div.card-body.cart-listing-body > div:nth-child(2) > div > p > label.prod_sku");

var productName = document.querySelector("#" + divId + " > div.card-body.cart-listing-body > div:nth-child(2) > div > p > label.prod_description");

var productPrice = document.querySelector("#" + divId + " > div.card-body.cart-listing-body > div:nth-child(2) > div > p > label.cart_price").innerHTML;

var prodR = productPrice.replace( " Price: ", "");

dataLayer.push({
'event':'add_to_cart',
'products': [{
  'id': productSku.innerHTML,
  'name': productName.innerHTML,
  'value': prodR,
  'quantity': 1
  }]
});

}, false);
})();
</script>
```

Here is the tag that fires on the "add_to_cart" event:

[image]

I've not published these tags yet, so everything has just been done in Preview.

It's it at all useful here are the the datalayers ...

Product 1 Added

[image]

Product 2 Added

[image]
[image]

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing the tag to fire the same number of times as the number of products added?